# 2D array in C, what t+= tab[i][j] means?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

```
int tab[][3] = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {6, 5, 4},
    {7, 8, 9}
};

main(){
   int i, j, t=0;
   for(i=2, j=0; i; i--, j++){
       t += tab[i][j++];
       printf("%d", t);
   }
```

I don't understand why the output is 11, firstly i =  2;  (7, 8, 9) and j = 0 and then t += tab[i][j++] this means 7, 8, 9 + (j++ which is 1 now) (2, 5, 8) which means 7 + 8 + 9 + 2 + 5 + 8? I don't get this. t += tab[i][j++]

Comment: It's a matrix. Example tab[1][1] would be {6,5,8}[1] which is 5

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code. You'll see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: @Parker thank you, i got it. but you mean {6, 5, 4} right?

Comment: @Shadow yes, that was a typo on my end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

First, it seems that you assume that `t += tab[i][j]` somehow adds a complete vector or a row to `t`, i.e. something like `(7,8,9)`. Yet an access to `tab[i][j]` stands for one particular cell value (not a row), and with `i==2, j==0`, this means `tab[2][0]` and yields value `7`.

Second, note that you have two statements that increment `j`, one in the `for`-part, and one in `tab[i][j++]` (note the `j++`). So when `i` decreases to `1`, `j` has actually increased to `2`, such that the second value will be `tab[1][2]`, which is `4`.

Then `7 + 4 = 11` should not be a surprise any longer :-).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First change `printf()` to  `printf("%d\n", t);` to see each `t` value in one line.

running program produce this output:

[image: program output]

as you see we have : `7` for first `t`,

before that you can use two simple for loop to print matrix all elements 
and have better view on its elements order.

If you make for loop indentation better you can decode the output results.
grab a pen and paper and draw variables of loop in each iteration.

```
   for(i=2, j=0  ;   i != 0  ;   i--, j++ ){
        t += tab[i][j++];
        printf("%d\n", t);
   }
```

first iteration `i:2 , j=0` as the condition `i != 0`(i.e i is not equals to 0 ) is true, then body of for is executed and we have   `t  += tab[2][0];'  'tab [2][0]` pointing to `7` (array index in C starts from Zero `0`) and because of value of t is 0,  now t holds 7  and simply printed on screen. after that `j++` in the tab[i]`[j++]` add one to `j` and now `j:1` as this for iteration has been finished two commands in the third part of for is executed now (`i--, j++`) and make values to `i:1 , j:2`.
we start second for iteration.
as the condition `i != 0` i still `true` we pass inside of for and 
t += tab[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m8kU.png)[2];    `tab[1][2] :4` and added to `t:7` we have now `t:7+4=11`
and print `t:11` on screen. now j added by one `j:3` and this iteration is finished goto third part of for `i--,j++` we have `i:0, j:4`.
in later iteration first we must check the for condition `i != 0` as now  `i:0` this condition is `False` and obviously for is finished.

This is my version

```
int tab[][3] = {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {6, 5, 4},
    {7, 8, 9}
};


//Main Program Function, Execution Part
int main()
{


       int i, j, t=0;

       for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
           printf("\n");
           for (int j=0;j<3;j++){
               printf("%d\t", tab[i][j]);
            }
       }

  printf("\n\n");

   for(i=2, j=0  ;   i != 0  ;   i--, j++ ){
        t += tab[i][j++];
        printf("%d\n", t);
   }

    system ("pause");
}
```